# Is there a certain IIS configuration required to allow a functioning .Net 4.0 ASP.Net MVC 2 Azure application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, azure

I just installed the Azure 1.2 tools update and would like to get to work on an Azure project running locally using ASP.Net MVC and .Net 4, but I cannot get MVC pages to load.

If I just create a new Azure project in VS 2010, add a ASP.Net MVC web role, and run the application, pages never load.  It appears that routing is somehow at fault as controller actions never get called, but if I add other pages to the project (like .htm or .aspx) they *will* load in the browser.

It all works fine with a new project using .Net 3.5, MVC 2 project in the Azure development environment; it all works fine with .Net 4.0 MVC 2 project that is not running in Azure; only the combination does not work.

Environment is Win 7 x64 (IIS 7.5), VS 2010, Azure tools 1.2

Is there some magic IIS setting I need to change or something?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have "HTTP Redirection" feature enabled.

See [here](http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2010/05/how-a-checkbox-saved-paving-my-machine.html)

Comment: I should have googled "how a checkbox saved paving my machine"...  You are hero to us all, or at least me.  Thanks

Comment: I was running into a 403.14 error, and that checkbox fixed this!